# Mathematica NIntegrate problem

Tags: numerical-integration

Here is my code:

[image]

The problem is that I always see these messages every time I run it

[image]

They always say " something has evaluated to a non-numerical values of all sample points in the region"

I try to add ?NumericQ in my function but it seems that I still get same errors.

I am entirely new to Mathematica. I hopes someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to create a function `myFun[t_?NumberQ] := Exp[ ... ] * Sqrt[ ... ]` and then do
`Im[NIntegrate[myFun[t], {t,0,Temp}]`. And please don't copy screenshots of code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code. Convert input cells to `InputForm` prior to copy and paste.

Comment: One of the issues might be how you defined your functions.  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037